# pandas rename index values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in pandas (python):

```
      B.  X.  Y.  
A
alpha 3. 5.  5
beta  9. 9.  11
```

I want to change 'alpha' for another name, like 'mu'. What should I do?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with parameter `index`
pass a dictionary to the `index` parameter

```
df.rename(index={'alpha': 'mu'})
```

[image]

Comment: don't forget to add `"inplace=True"` (pandas 1.2.1)

Comment: My tendency was to provide answers that didn't overwrite the existing dataframe.  However, you bring up a good point.  Keep in mind that this produces a copy of the dataframe with renamed index values and should be assigned to a variable name in order to make it persist.  If you wanted to augment the existing dataframe then by all means use `inplace=True`

Comment: But if you have duplicates in the indexes the rename does not affect all of them.