# Pandas Mapping 2 dfs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I want to perform a mapping from 2 fields in df to 1 another df1.  However, the field name for df1 is empty.
df:

```
Name1  Name2 Value
x      x-y      1
x      x-z      2
y      y-z      3
y      y-x      5
z      z-y      7
```

df1:  (Is it possible to give a name to this empty slot?)

```
      Num     
x     1
y     2
z     3
a     4
a-b   5
x-y   0
x-z   5
y-z   0
y-x   5
z-y   0
```

The output would be:

```
Name1  Name2 Value  Num1   Num2
x      x-y      1     1     0
x      x-z      2     1     5
y      y-z      3     2     0
y      y-x      5     2     5
z      z-y      7     3     0
```

Thank you and happy holidays!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am choosing `map` , you can also try `merge` and `join`, try look at index, in `merge` should be `df1.merge(df2,left_on='Name1',right_index=True)`

```
df['Num1']=df.Name1.map(df1.Num)
df['Num2']=df.Name2.map(df1.Num)
df
Out[1150]: 
  Name1 Name2  Value  Num1  Num2
0     x   x-y      1     1     0
1     x   x-z      2     1     5
2     y   y-z      3     2     0
3     y   y-x      5     2     5
4     z   z-y      7     3     0
```

Another way

```
df=df.set_index('Value').stack()
df.map(df1.Num)

pd.concat([df,df.map(df1.Num)],1).unstack()
Out[1169]: 
          0           1      
      Name1 Name2 Name1 Name2
Value                        
1         x   x-y     1     0
2         x   x-z     1     5
3         y   y-z     2     0
5         y   y-x     2     5
7         z   z-y     3     0
```

Comment: How did you create your dataframes? This code results in an AttributeError for me.

Comment: Got it. Had an unrelated error in my notebook that was throwing syntax errors. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Evan Yw~:-), Happy holiday

Comment: Is there a way to rename the unnamed column in df1, before or without the merge operation? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096611/how-to-rename-an-empty-column-header-in-a-pandas-dataframe-without-exporting-t

I wasn't able to get those solutions to work.

Comment: @Evan Wen was faster than me, so I can at least help with the renaming part. This is how to do it: First reset the index (the unnamed column is actually not a column but an index) df1 = df1.reset_index() Then rename it:
df1.rename(columns={'index':'Name3'}, inplace=True)

Comment: @Evan that is index, not the column . if you want , you can rename the index by df1.index.rename('Some you want'), to convert it to column df1.reset_index()

Comment: @Wen Thanks.  Is there a way to name that colum in df1 with no heading?  I forgot to mention that my df1 has duplicate values.  In order to use the mapping method, I need to remove dup first but the drop_dup function will also remove the rows if the value in the Num are the same.  
Nice new profile pic btw :)

Comment: @TylerNG Yes, you can name the index: `df.index.name = ...`, or use `df.rename_axis`.

Comment: @TylerNG df.rename(columns={'':'somvalue'})

Comment: @TylerNG or like this: First reset the index (the unnamed column is actually not a column but an index) df1 = df1.reset_index() Then rename it: df1.rename(columns={'index':'Name3'}, inplace=True)

Comment: You guys make coding looks easy :)  Thanks all.  Happy holidays!

Comment: @TylerNG happy coding and happy holiday :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
You could use `loc` + `values` -

```
df.assign(
    Num1=df2.loc[df.Name1].values, Num2=df2.loc[df.Name2].values
)

  Name1 Name2  Value  Num1  Num2
0     x   x-y      1     1     0
1     x   x-z      2     1     5
2     y   y-z      3     2     0
3     y   y-x      5     2     5
4     z   z-y      7     3     0
```

---

**Option 2**
Another interesting alternative with `loc` + `concat` -

```
i = df2.loc[df.values[:, :2].ravel()].values
j = pd.DataFrame(i.reshape(len(df), -1), columns=['Num1', 'Num2'])

pd.concat([df, j], 1)


  Name1 Name2  Value  Num1  Num2
0     x   x-y      1     1     0
1     x   x-z      2     1     5
2     y   y-z      3     2     0
3     y   y-x      5     2     5
4     z   z-y      7     3     0
```

Comment: Happy holiday :-)

Answer (score 1):

Moving this out of the comments just for visibility:

```
      Num     
x     1
y     2
z     3
a     4
a-b   5
x-y   0
x-z   5
y-z   0
y-x   5
z-y   0

df1 = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Output:

```
     Num
x      1
y      2
z      3
a      4
a-b    5
x-y    0
x-z    5
y-z    0
y-x    5
z-y    0
```

The column of letter(s) is the index. To rename it, you must use 
@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution:

`df.index.name = 'name'`

If you attempt to rename the index as you would a column, it does not work (with or without `inplace = True`):

```
df1.rename(columns = {'': 'Name'}, inplace = True)
print(df1)
```

returns:

```
     Num
x      1
y      2
z      3
a      4
a-b    5
x-y    0
x-z    5
y-z    0
y-x    5
z-y    0
```

Thanks for the discussion.

[pandas rename index values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855900/pandas-rename-index-values)

Answer (score 1):

Perfect answers are already given, but I just have a note. If you haven't renamed the unnamed column (which is called an index), the posted solutions will work perfectly. I'll show how I do the renaming, and answer how to do the join after the renaming.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

# Create df
rawText = StringIO("""
Name1  Name2 Value
x      x-y      1
x      x-z      2
y      y-z      3
y      y-x      5
z      z-y      7
""")
df = pd.read_csv(rawText, sep = "\s+")

#Create df1 by renaming the unnamed index as Name3
rawText = StringIO("""
      Num     
x     1
y     2
z     3
a     4
a-b   5
x-y   0
x-z   5
y-z   0
y-x   5
z-y   0
""")
df1 = pd.read_csv(rawText, sep = "\s+")
df1 = df1.reset_index() # This works when you have multiple unnamed indices too
df1.rename(columns={'index':'Name3'}, inplace=True)

# Here is the solution
df.merge(df1, left_on='Name1', right_on='Name3')
```

Very fruitful discussion, happy holidays!